# Java syntax - if without using codeblocks

Tags: java

```
if(true)    
  System.out.println("one");   
System.out.println("two);
System.out.println("three);
```

First it seems weird but it works. My question is just for clarification: if I don't use code blocks anything after if will be affected; if I use codeblock just inside the codeblocks will be affected - am I right? or is there something that I dont know happening through this example?

Comment: What else were you expecting?  This doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Because when I try this I expect an error but it works. I know its just common sense but what if I just clarifying things.

Comment: You would expect a syntax error, or things to not print?  (Also, on a side note, do people not learn about blocks anymore?  This is like fifth question like this in 3 days -- don't mean that in mean way, just curious.)

Answer (score 9):

Your case is equivalent to:

```
if(true){
    System.out.println("one");
}
System.out.println("two");
System.out.println("three");
```

and output will be

```
one
two
three
```

`if` statement executes operator (in your case, it's only `System.out.println("one")`, that follows behind it. Figure braces (`{}`) is operator too. For example:

```
if(false)
System.out.println("one");
System.out.println("two");
System.out.println("three");

/*output will be:
two
three
*/

//and in this case there will be no output
if(false){
    System.out.println("one");
    System.out.println("two");
    System.out.println("three");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java if can be written in  two ways

```
if(true){
//statement 1
//statement 2
//statement 3
}
```

if you want to execute multiple lines, you have to use block. If you want to use single line you can use with out block.

```
if(true)
//statement 1
```

but one line statement also can be written in block, it will work same.

```
if(true){
//statment 1
}
```

works same as with out block

Answer (score 0):

In Java (and in similar languages), a single statement is equivalent to a block containing that single statement.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Language Specification for the if statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9) defines:

```
IfThenStatement:
    if ( Expression ) Statement
```

Statement is further [defined as](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5):

```
Statement:
    StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
    <removed for brevity>

StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement:
    Block
    <removed for brevity>
```

In other words: An if statement contains a `Statement`, which can be a `Block` (which is a list of statements between brackets).